# how to solve read only file system error in android programming with eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, itext

I am developing a program in which i must create pdf file inside application.

This is the code that i use for creating pdf file but an error occurred that say

```
"/Image.pdf:open failed:EROFS(read-only file system)"
```

This is my button click code:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("Image.pdf"));
document.open();
Image image1 = Image.getInstance("watermark.png");
document.add(image1);
String imageUrl = "http://jenkov.com/images/20081123-20081123-3E1W7902-small-portrait.jpg";
Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
document.add(image2);
document.close();
```

Comment: which location have you store pdf ?

Comment: i tested more about this but i think it is in root directory of my phones PhoneMemory.

Comment: have you added read permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: i added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> before <application tag

Comment: if my code has some problem please say about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write pdf in sdcard root directory:

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"Image.pdf"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the pdf file created. but when i want to open it, an error occur and say "the document can not be opened because it is corrupted or damaged"

Answer (score 0):

first i thank Haresh Chhelana for his answers.

by using this code i can create new pdf file with an image in it.

```
Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Image.pdf"));
            document.open();
            Image image1 = Image.getInstance(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/01.jpg");
            document.add(image1);
            document.close();
```